# Flash Starling dispatching Events

Tags: actionscript-3, events, dispatch, starling-framework

Is it possible to send data to a starling object after instantiating it?
`var mStarling:Starling = new Starling(StarlingClass, stage);`

Or by dispatching events from main class and then listen for these events in the starling class?

Comment: I suggested to use static methods in main class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441734/send-data-from-flash-to-starling-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can pass events between a normal display object and a starling display object. The main reason behind this being the fact that all Starling Display Objects are drawn on the GPU or rather stage3d .

A normal event in Flash travels through the whole display list. Since stage3d is not part of the display list, I dont think stage3d objects can listen to your events.

I would suggest you to explore options like [as3 signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) to achieve the same. This should work since an as3 signal is independent of the display list hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely listen for an event with a Starling class just as you would any other class.

For example, in starling class you could do something like..

```
this.addEventListener( "CustomEvent", PROCESS_METHOD );
```

Then, in your main class you can call..

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("CustomEvent"));
```

If you'd like to pass values in you'll need to either attach the event to a dynamic object that mStarling has access to (like a MovieClip). Or you can actually create an object that extends Event that you can dispatch instead of new Event("CustomEvent");

Comment: When listening To events, I should dispatch event to that object on which i asigned event listener, like so. mc.dispatchEvent(new Event("CustomEvent")); and then maybe from mc object class this.addEventListener( "CustomEvent", PROCESS_METHOD ); but how can starling object and main stage have assecc to same object?

Comment: what actually you put instead of `this` here : `this.addEventListener` ?